# How can I block ads hosts on my IPSec VPN server?

Tags: vpn

I have created a VPN service with IPSec VPN server on Ubuntu server. I'm trying block ads hosts for Android. So when users use my VPN, no Ads will show up on their Android device.

Comment: Maybe something like pi-hole https://pi-hole.net/

Comment: @edwinksl I just installed it. It didn't work. Ads still showing up.

Comment: It is difficult to do as you would need to somehow maintain a blacklist of blocked sites and it is difficult to know what to allow and what to bloock as you get a larger and larger user base. I suggest you look at something along the lines of opendns or a proxyserver. IMO, however, best allow your users the freedom and allow them to install adblock for android if they wish, several options available, adblock browser is great - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.adblockplus.browser&hl=en